# Why does QGIS convert 'NoData' values to 'Zero'?

Tags: qgis, convert, imagery, nodata, sentinel-2

I'm trying to convert a clipped multi-spectral sentinel-2 image in QGIS to an 8-bit rendered image in a different CRS. I've clipped the image to the coastline and defined the other unwanted areas of the image as no data values. However, when I save the rendered image, all the no data values are converted to zero, which then causes a problem when I finally convert the image to a single band 8-bit image. All the no data values which have been converted to zero produce a black background around the image, which I don't want. I can't remove the zero values, because there are zero values elsewhere in the image which I require, values representing water, shadow etc... Is there any way to save a rendered image without converting the no data values to zero?

Comment: Not all formats support suitable nodata values. For 8-bit imagery, even the no data value has to be within the 8-bits available - with the most suitable being 0 or 255.